# Added nouveau.modeset=0 now black screen and nothing

Tags: boot, grub2

Running Ubuntu 18.04.2. My system is crypt.

I was having an issue where Ubuntu didn't seem to be waking up after screen idle timeout and lock. I would have to hard crash the system and then reboot.

Followed suggestion on this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep>) to enter nouveau.modeset=0 to grub. After doing that and sudo update-grub and a reboot, now I never see the bios setup options, never see the enter crypt password. Can't CTRL+ALT+F1, F6, or F7. Totally screwed my system. I can't ssh in either.

Don't enter nouveau.modeset=0!

So now what? How do I get back into my system? I've tried without being able to see anything at all to enter my crypt password. Then going through the motions of trying to login blind and possibly set my grub back, but it is not working. Just blank! It drives me nuts that this is an issue in this day and age. Should just work.

Comment: `nouveau.modeset=0` is a kernel parameter and thus only affects the kernel which is booted _after_ grub. It is possible that something went wrong when you ran `update-grub`, but a corrupted grub would still not affect any stages before grub, i.e. the BIOS/UEFI setup. I'd guess that fast boot is enabled in your BIOS and therefore you don't see any "Press this or that key to enter setup..." message. Either try pressing/holding any of the usual suspects (F2, Del, Esc,...) immediately after turning on the computer, or look up the correct procedure in the computer's manual.

Comment: The Dell Precision 3420 is bricked at this point thanks to nouveau.modeset=0. I tried flashing the bios. Every single key known to man. Rebooted a hundred times and no bios, nothing.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions from Dell support [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/dedhs1/sln300716/bios-recovery-options-on-a-dell-pc-or-tablet) and [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln284985/how-to-perform-a-bios-or-cmos-reset-and-or-clear-the-nvram-on-your-dell-system)?

Comment: Tried the suggestions, still nothing. Unbelievable. Wish I had not put in nouveau.modeset=0. Not sure what to do at this point. Terrible lesson learned. Don't mess with the grub file on certain systems and if you do make sure you know what you're doing. Following someone's "fix" could be very, very bad.